# How i know if it is last term in hierarchy

Tags: 2013, term-store, term, term-set

In managed metadata service term store, I am iterating through all the groups, all termSets and all terms up to last level. I can iterate through group, termSet and root term (`test1.1` in example below). In my case I have 4 or even more levels of terms, how i get to know if it is last term in terms hierarchy. which property or method will give this information? For example in below terms hierarchy how I get to know the last term programmatically? For example `test1.1.1`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of properties `Terms` or `TermsCount`. This property provides the list of immediate Terms. So in your case you can use following logic

```
if(term.Terms == null || term.Terms.Count == 0)
    //means this term has no childern

if(term.TermsCount == 0)
    //means this term has no childern
```